# How to upload files into google drive via api using Python?

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I have an excel file in my local computer that I would like to upload into google drive using python via an API.

The following is my code:

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None
def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/Users/shruthiravishankar/Downloads/client_secret_316665721335-819139d5ea0aeet1ddshhk6p0mpl8mv2.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
API_NAME = 'Desktop client 1'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES =['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

folder_id='10Xct2T1vBpqW3-3Ud6mjPuf_lKCN1bUL'
file_names = ['Manual_SIC_MVP (9).xlsx']
mime_types = ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']

for file_name, mime_type in zip(file_names, mime_types):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': file_name, 
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload('/Users/shruthiravishankar/Downloads/{0}'.format(file_name), mimetype=mime_type)
    
    print(media)

    service.files().create(
        supportsTeamDrives=True,
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
```

The error that I am getting is:

Unable to connect and none files.

[image]

Is there an issue with he api_version and scope? Unable to figure out the issue. This is my first time dealing with api.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this statement actually:

```py
API_NAME = 'Desktop client 1'
```

That's not a valid Google service name.

This particular library needs to know which API service it needs to build, not how you want to call it.

Change that line to the following:

```py
API_NAME = 'drive'
```

See the github line in question [here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/main/drive/quickstart/quickstart.py#L53) and the general quickstart docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python#step_2_configure_the_sample)